# Modifying Maven POM to Get File Locally

Tags: configuration, maven

My mvn build is trying to grab the following file from an online repository.

```
http://BAD_WEBSITE/repositories/smpsnapshots/org/jboss/aop/jboss-aop/
2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
```

However, that URL no longer exists.

I have the maven-metadata.xml file saved locally, but how can I modify my POM file to get the file locally?

Here's where my config file specifies this bad URL to find the file.

SNAPSHOT.pom

```
     <distributionManagement>    <!-- Declare the release repository to deploy the 
.zip file to -->
         <repository>
           <id>smpreleases</id>
           <name>Releases</name>
           <url>http://BAD_WEBSITE/content/repositories/smpreleases</url>
         </repository>
         <!-- Declare the snapshot repository to deploy the .zip file to -->
         <snapshotRepository>
           <id>smpsnapshots</id>
           <name>Snapshots</name>
           <url>http://BAD_WEBSITE/content/repositories/smpsnapshots</url>
         </snapshotRepository>    
     </distributionManagement>
```

Answer (score 0):

Any quick fix will just be temporary; you will run into the same problem over & over again, and have a hard time manually managing the situation. The easiest & most robust solution to this issue  (and related problems: missing dependencies, down servers, working disconnected) are all easily remedied by simply installing your own local maven repository. (And it really is simple: [nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) is IMO the easiest.)

Once this is done (as simple [as unzip](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/_installing_nexus.html) & [start the server](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/install-sect-running.html)), then point all your maven projects to this local server. (It can be on localhost, or another server on your network.) Assuming nexus for the moment, [configure it to be a mirror](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html) of all the remote repo's you use. It'll cache these artifacts for you, speeding up new builds on new projects and/or new servers. And now you can push (deploy) to this server too, to share your artifacts with your other maven projects. Things can be staged here & tested (e.g,. jenkins/hudson) before deployed to a public repository (if you do that).

Just remember:

- any non-snapshot artifacts only have one checksum (sha1/md5) and should always be universally unique -- so it doesn't matter if they come from your local mirror or real remote. (Don't generate the same release artifact more than once.)
- don't put repository info in your pom; put all that in `settings.xml` : either `~/.m2/settings.xml` or run maven with `mvn -s path/to/my/settings.xml`